# Calling a javascript function on pre_render

Tags: c#, asp.net, prototypejs

I am using prototype, and i have a function as follows:

```
MyJSClass.prototype.AddLetters = function()
{
}
```

I would like to call this from c# based on some conditions i need to evaluate on pre-render.

Comment: what do you mean, exactly, by `"I want to call this from C#"`?  Are you saying you want the server to invoke the method in the user's browser?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try with this code

```
 ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

 String yourScript= "function();";
 cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key script", yourScript, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't directly call JavaScript code from C# - especially before the page is rendered, you need a way of:

1. communicating the requirement/condition to the JavaScript code
2. picking up and appropriately dealing with the requirement/condition at the right time.

For 1. I recommend using the ClientScriptManager to insert/modify a variable, although there are other options below.

For 2. you should probably add some javascript which will pick up the communication.

Options for 1.:

- Add a field into the page
- Add a script into the page (e.g. using the Client ScriptManager) which will set a variable
- Inject the script into the page directly at the relevant point for it to run
- set a flag in the C# which you then check when you receive an AJAX call (which you might use if it will change according to server-side rules while the page is open...)